# Отслеживание появления нового процесса Windows

Tags: c++, windows, процесс

Добрый день. Надо отследить появление новых процессов. Есть ли в Windows слот, на который поступает сигнал при появлении нового процесса? Иначе как это можно реализовать? В psapi подобного не нашёл. Есть предположение через определённые интервалы времени сверять список PID, но надеюсь найти более простое решение.

Comment: Может, поставить хук на CreateProcess?

Comment: А зачем вам их отслеживать? Пишите [анти]вирус?

Comment: @VTT органайзер, чтобы много времени за играми и всякими ненужностями не проводить

Comment: @АлексейСаровский можете объяснить что вы имеете ввиду? Я плохо разбираюсь в работе с процессами пока что

Comment: Тогда проверять процесса вам вообще ни к чему, ведь запущенный процесс не говорит о том, что пользователь с ним работает. Просто проверяйте окна.

Comment: @VTT ваша правда, так удобнее будет, но вопрос открыт, хотя бы для общего развития

Comment: Раз вам не нужна микросекундная точность, достаточно перечислять процессы и проверять появление новых. Это определенно проще, чем получать "сигнал" при запуске нового процесса.

Comment: Для этого надо WMI. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390425(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Для какой версии windows? Поскольку, ЕМНИП, начиная с Windows 8, подход для такого отслеживания будет несколько другим.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov для 7. А сильно различается?

Comment: @ProstoNekitos У меня в заначке есть вариант, проверяющий создание новых процессов через ZwQuerySystemInformation. Формально, эта функция не рекомендуется к использованию, начиная с Windows 8, но проверил сейчас на Windows 10, - работает. Код на Delphi, но принцип вы легко поймёте, сейчас выложу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать трейсинг через системную функцию  [ZwQuerySystemInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725506(v=vs.85).aspx). Внимание! Microsoft не рекомендует, начиная с Windows 8, её использовать, предлагая замену, но, как проверено только что на Windows 10, она работает.

Пример реализации и использования привожу на Delphi, в виде консольного приложения. Поскольку речь касается функций WinAPI, переписать на C/C++ - легко.

```
program ListOfProcess;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  windows,
  System.Generics.Collections;

// поскольку подход писался очень давно (во времена Windows 2000), 
// типы и константы определены, поскольку в то время их ещё не было  в 
// системных модулях Delphi. Хотя и сейчас, возможно, некоторых нет.


type
  NTStatus = cardinal;
  PVOID    = pointer;
  USHORT = WORD;
  UCHAR = byte;
  PWSTR = PWideChar;

const

  STATUS_SUCCESS              = NTStatus($00000000);
  STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED        = NTStatus($C0000022);
  STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH = NTStatus($C0000004);

const SystemProcessesAndThreadsInformation = 5;

type
PClientID = ^TClientID;
TClientID = packed record

 UniqueProcess:cardinal;
 UniqueThread:cardinal;
end;

PUnicodeString = ^TUnicodeString;
  TUnicodeString = packed record
    Length: Word;
    MaximumLength: Word;
    Buffer: PWideChar;
end;

PVM_COUNTERS = ^VM_COUNTERS;
VM_COUNTERS = packed record
   PeakVirtualSize,
   VirtualSize,
   PageFaultCount,
   PeakWorkingSetSize,
   WorkingSetSize,
   QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage,
   QuotaPagedPoolUsage,
   QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage,
   QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage,
   PagefileUsage,
   PeakPagefileUsage: dword;
  end;

PIO_COUNTERS = ^IO_COUNTERS;
IO_COUNTERS = packed record

   ReadOperationCount,
   WriteOperationCount,
   OtherOperationCount,
   ReadTransferCount,
   WriteTransferCount,
   OtherTransferCount: LARGE_INTEGER;
  end;

PSYSTEM_THREADS = ^SYSTEM_THREADS;
SYSTEM_THREADS = packed record
  KernelTime,
  UserTime,
  CreateTime: LARGE_INTEGER;
  WaitTime: dword;
  StartAddress: pointer;
  ClientId: TClientId;
  Priority,
  BasePriority,
  ContextSwitchCount: dword;
  State: dword;
  WaitReason: dword;
 end;

PSYSTEM_PROCESSES = ^SYSTEM_PROCESSES;
SYSTEM_PROCESSES = packed record
   NextEntryDelta,
   ThreadCount: dword;
   Reserved1 : array [0..5] of dword;
   CreateTime,
   UserTime,
   KernelTime: LARGE_INTEGER;
   ProcessName: TUnicodeString;
   BasePriority: dword;
   ProcessId,
   InheritedFromProcessId,
   HandleCount: dword;
   Reserved2: array [0..1] of dword;
   VmCounters: VM_COUNTERS;
   IoCounters: IO_COUNTERS;

   Threads: array [0..0] of SYSTEM_THREADS;
  end;

// основная функция, которую мы будем использовать

Function ZwQuerySystemInformation(ASystemInformationClass: dword;
                                  ASystemInformation: Pointer;
                                  ASystemInformationLength: dword;
                                  AReturnLength:PCardinal): NTStatus;
                                  stdcall;external 'ntdll.dll';


// Функция получения буфера с системной информацией
Function GetInfoTable(ATableType:dword):Pointer;
var
 mSize: dword;
 mPtr: pointer;
 St: NTStatus;
begin
 Result := nil;
 mSize := $4000; //начальный размер буфера

 repeat // подгонка размера буфера
   mPtr := VirtualAlloc(nil, mSize, MEM_COMMIT or MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
   if mPtr = nil then Exit;
   St := ZwQuerySystemInformation(ATableType, mPtr, mSize, nil);
   if St = STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH then

      begin
        VirtualFree(mPtr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        mSize := mSize * 2;
      end;
 until St <> STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH;
 if St = STATUS_SUCCESS
   then Result := mPtr
   else VirtualFree(mPtr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

end;
// приведу пример использовании фунции:
var info, info2: PSystem_Processes;
    i, j, k: integer;
    t, t1: LARGE_INTEGER;
    process_id:TDictionary<Integer,SYSTEM_PROCESSES>; // здесь будем хранить информацию
begin
  process_id := TDictionary<Integer,SYSTEM_PROCESSES>.Create;

  // Список процессов на момент старта программы
    info := GetInfoTable(SystemProcessesAndThreadsInformation);
    info2 := info;

    while (info2^.NextEntryDelta <> 0) do

    begin
      if not process_id.ContainsKey(info2^.ProcessId) then
         process_id.Add(info2^.ProcessId, info2^);
      info2 := Pointer(dword(info2)+info2^.NextEntryDelta);
    end;

    VirtualFree(info, 0, MEM_RELEASE);


  while true do // нужно вставить вариант выхода из цикла. Разумеется, Ctrl+C всегда сработает :)
  begin
    Sleep(2000); // будем проверять наличие новых процессов каждые 2 секунды
    info := GetInfoTable(SystemProcessesAndThreadsInformation);
    info2 := info;

    while (info2^.NextEntryDelta <> 0) do

    begin
      if not process_id.ContainsKey(info2^.ProcessId)
        then
          begin
            writeln(info2^.ProcessId, ' - появился');
            process_id.Add(info2^.ProcessId,info2^); // если будем постоянно добавлять, словарь разрастётся,
// надо бы подумать и об удалении элементов, оставляю ТС :)
          end;
      info2 := Pointer(dword(info2)+info2^.NextEntryDelta);
    end;
    VirtualFree(info, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
  end;
  process_id.Free;
end.
```